# Add column to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, oledb, datarow

I'm working with ASP.NET in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. When I did my database I had Microsoft Access. Now I don't have it (have tried to get it), so I thought that the best idea is to change my table with code. I want to add a column to my table that can fit pictures. How do I do it? I thought that I do an ***.aspx*** file(Webpage), then in the ***.aspx.cs*** file I write my code. I run it once changing my table and have what I want and delete that file. Is there another way without other programs?

My table is called **item** and I want to add the column that can have a picture. What's the code for that? ***Thanks!***

Comment: You can't easily manage a database writing code every time you want to do something.  Install the proper client.

Comment: What do you mean with client? Software program?

Comment: If it's an Access database install Access.  If it's SQL server install SQL server mgmt studio.  If you really want to add a column, send an `ALTER TABLE` command to the database.

Comment: Why don't you use the client tool SQL Server Management Studio? Unless you want to re-invent every variation in datamodelling that's already usable in SSMS. If so, the easiest way is to learn SQL and kick of the necessary queries to update/change your database from code (even that would be easier todo in SSMS).

Comment: @RickS I can't find where to install Access(I don't have money for buying it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ALTER TABLE` Command:

```
ALTER TABLE item ADD COLUMN picture varbinary
```

Comment: What do I put instead of {datatype}?

Comment: you can use the `varbinary` datatype

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add the column using SQL, which I am assuming you are familiar with.

`ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name column-definition;`
So that is something you would want to run 1 time and make sure you define the column correctly;

Alternatively, you can edit the **Table Definition** from the server explorer by right clicking on the table and clicking table definition. Then you can add or change what ever you like.